# Boost range adaptors

Tags: c++, boost, range, boost-range

When using range adaptors in a find algorithm, I have to repeat all the adaptor chain to get the corresponding end() iterator. e.g:

```
std::vector<size_t> numbers = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 2, 1, 3,3,50, 55} ;

if ( find(numbers|reversed,99) != (numbers|reversed).end() )
                                 //^adaptor chain repeated
{
    std::cout << "FOUND!!!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to get the corresponding end iterator without having to repeat it again?

Comment: Stick it in a variable?

Comment: Well, that would be the obvious solution, but for my liking it defeats a bit the purpose of the range adaptors

Answer (score 1):

Too bad that `find` calls often end up verbose – it's even worse with STL than with Boost ranges. You could introduce a little helper function:

```
template<class SinglePassRange, class Value>
bool contains(SinglePassRange& rng, Value const &val) {
  return boost::find(rng, val) != rng.end();
}
```

I didn't test this so it probably doesn't compile, but you get the idea.